# How to write useful queries in KIbana and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a documents in Elasticsearch with the following structure:

```
{
  "_index": "logstash-2018.05.11",
  "_type": "doc",
  "_id": "LSg_T2MB-uso043FSCvT",
  "_version": 1
  "_source": {
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2018-05-11T12:48:57.447Z",
    "filename": "VARIABLEPART_COMMONPART"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2018-05-11T12:48:57.447Z"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to write some queries that allow me to count the aggregated documents for VARIABLEPART.
Also, I would like to make sure that the result of my queries can be viewed with Kibana, but I do not know where to start !

Comment: Start with [Count API] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html#search-count) defined in ElasticSearch [APIs] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search.html)

Comment: GET /twitter/_doc/_count
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}

This is first example...
"term" is a syntax keyword ?